# Target active list group item with # in url

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm implementing a list group with this set up on my website and I would like to activate certain tabs based on a # in the url. (ex. www.example.com/page.html#active-tab)

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-vertical-tab

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.products-tab-menu>div.list-group>a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('a.active').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var index = $(this).index();
        $("div.products-tab>div.products-tab-content").removeClass("active");
        $("div.products-tab>div.products-tab-content").eq(index).addClass("active");
    });
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please try and code this yourself here using the code tool - then you'll find people can jump in and help you!

Comment: I've added the script i'm executing on the page, i thought the link would be helpful for reference as I'm essentially mirroring that setup.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.hash` contains the URL part after (including) the hash character.
Take the tab name from here.

First, every `div.products-tab>div.products-tab-content` must have unique name or class (I would give them the tab name). Then you could just write:

```
tabName = window.location.hash.substr(1);
$("div.products-tab>div.products-tab-content").removeClass("active");
$('div.products-tab>div.products-tab-content[name="'+tabName+'"]').addClass("active");
```

Not tested, but should work.